# Sockets: I/O Error 32

Tags: sockets, multithreading, network-programming, poco

Could someone please explain what an I/O Error 32 refers to in the context of a network socket?

I have a multithreaded Socks5 server written using Poco SocketReactors and am getting this error when the server load reaches a certain point. The exception is thrown within my onReadable handlers at the same time across all threads which have connections associated with them. The only other thing I am doing within those threads is std::cout but I am not sure if this is a potential cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify what platform you are on, but my wild-ass guess is that this refers to `errno 32`, which as `EPIPE` on a POSIX system. The likeliest scenario for that is that you're trying to read from a socket when the remote side has closed the connection.

Comment: I am on Linux x64. In my Google searches I did see an error 32 referred to but not specifically in the context of a socket. The error referred to a broken pipe so I guess this agrees with what you are saying.